# Using Angular and Rails: Bcrypt throwing an error when trying to create user

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on the app that use Angular and Rails. I am trying to create new user, but keep getting this error:

```
BCrypt::Errors::InvalidHash (invalid hash):
 app/models/user.rb:14:in `new'
 app/models/user.rb:14:in `password'
 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

It seems like Angular is creating a password, but it is not getting passed to Rails.

```
Parameters: {"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Smith", "email"=>"john.smith@gmail.com", "username"=>"johnsmith", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"John", "last_name"=>"Smith", "username"=>"johnsmith", "email"=>"john.smith@gmail.com"}}
```

Here is what my frontend code looks like:

**app.js**

```js
$scope.signUp = function() {
  var newUser = {first_name: $scope.firstName, last_name: $scope.lastName, email: $scope.email, username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}
  $http.post('http://localhost:3000/users', newUser)
    .success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.errors) {
        console.log(data.errors);
      }
      else {
        $location.path("/sign_in");
      }
    })
};
```

**signup.html**

```html
<div class="form-group has-success signup-box">
  <form name="signupForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="firstName"/>
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="lastName"/>
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email"/>
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username"/>
    <input type="text" ng-required="true" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password"/>
    <input type="submit" ng-disabled="signupForm.$invalid" class="form-control btn btn-success" value="Sign Up" ng-click="signUp()" />
  </form>
  <a href="/#/sign_in">Sign In</a>
</div>
```

And the backend code:

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      render json: "You successfully create account. Please log in with your information."
    else
      render json: user
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
require 'bcrypt'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include BCrypt

  ***

  validates :first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password, presence: true

  ***

  def password
    @password ||= Password.new(password_hash)
  end

  def password=(new_password)
    @password = Password.create(new_password)
    self.password_hash = @password
  end
end
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of the error. Apparently, Rails did not like the format of data being passed in. In the **app.js** file on the line 2 (see the question) I replaced:

```
{first_name: $scope.firstName, last_name: $scope.lastName, email: $scope.email, username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}'
```

with

```
{user: {first_name: $scope.firstName, last_name: $scope.lastName, email: $scope.email, username: $scope.username, password: $scope.password}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution totally works. Another version of doing it is to delete the name spacing in the `user_params` method in `users_controller`:

```
def user_params
  params.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password)
end
```

instead of,

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :username, :email, :password)
end
```